# How can i loop through all my .fasta files?

Tags: loops, unix, blast

I wrote a code to go through all my .fasta files in my directory but it is not working. I want it to match with my -db Viral.fna and output (fasta file name).txt and -outfmt 6

I tried 2 different codes

```
for f in file1.fasta file2.fasta etc ...
do blastn -db Viral.fna -query $f.fasta  -out $f_output3.txt -outfmt 6
Done
```

Which didn't work: gave me this error

```
Command line argument error: Argument "query". File is not accessible:  `file1.fasta.fasta'and repeated for all the files
```

I also tried this :

```
for f in 'ls *.fasta' 
do  blastn -db Viral.fna -query $f  -out $f_output3.txt -outfmt 6
Done
```

Can someone help me out with figure out how to make this loop work I keep getting an error that says

```
Too many positional arguments (1), the offending value: 123.fasta
```

Comment: Please, use the `{}` button in the editor to mark data and code.

Comment: Oh thank you i did not know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .fasta extension is already part of $f, so don't add it. And if there's whitespace in any of the file names you have to use quotes where you use $f:

```
-query "$f" -out "$f"_output3.txt
```

Also, when you write $f_output3.txt, the shell will think you want use a variable called f_output3 which doesn't exist

Comment: I used this and it worked 
for f in  *.fasta 
do blastn -db Viral.fna -query "$f" -out "$f"_output3.txt -outfmt 6